# Multiply copies of assemblies are loaded into the memory by ASP.NET server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-assembly, appdomain

I have web server which hosts ASP.NET. I used SysInternal process explorer and find that the several version of each dll from server bin folder are loaded. Assemblies are loaded from  \Temporary ASP.NET Files\ directory. I don't understand why server is loading several same assemblies. Two same .NET assemblies in the same Application Domain can't be loaded. Neither  it the default  load context, nor load from context(i see that there is only 1 appDomain). Only with non context with reflection like fromFile  method. But how can that be? Don't understand at all... I am not very experience in ASP.NET, maybe i don't know something?

---

[image: screen shot frome the proces explorer]
<sub>(source: [lbs.com.ua](http://lbs.com.ua/downloads/ScreenShot0251.jpg))</sub>

[screen shot AppDomains http://lbs.com.ua/downloads/ScreenShot027.jpg](http://lbs.com.ua/downloads/ScreenShot027.jpg)

Comment: Are any files changed during execution, like a CMS writing aspx/ascx files? That would result in a recompilation of that file into a new assembly, but not necessarily a complete reload of the appdomain (and unloading of old assemblies).

Comment: no. the assemblies witch are loaded several times aren't changing. some of them are external referenced back end assemblies.

Comment: You say that several versions of each dll is loaded. Do you mean that it's several instances of the same dll file? Could you provides us with paths to the files to a few of these files, perhaps with screenshots of what Process Explorer is showing?

Comment: You see in screen shot, for example, that there is two loaded instance of the DevExpress.Charts.v12.1.Core.dll. But there is only one file DevExpress.Charts.v12.1.Core.dll in the app bin folder..

Comment: The headers in your screenshot suggest that this is the lower pane loaded with the list of dlls loaded. This view is not enough to verify that you do not actually have several appdomains. Check the properties for the w3wp.exe process, and verify what appdomains you have under the tab .NET Assemblies. Here you'll find a list of all domains and which assemblies they have loaded. No other view will provide this data. Use it to verify that you only have one appdomain (named /LM/W3SVC/...), except for the SharedDomain/DefaultDomain.

Comment: I add AppDomains Window. As you see - there are 2 domains and one shared(with only mscorlib).  Our ASP.NET Development server is hosts on the same process as our service but in other app domain(3 domain in list).

Comment: What are the file paths? Probably the same file name in different folders.

Comment: Not. For example DevExpress.Charts.v12.1.Core.dll are have only one copy in the wer server bin folder.

Comment: @BransDs the paths on the screenshot are not in the bin folder. There are other copies, probably shadow copied ones. Please examine them.

Answer (score 2):

This is the folder where ASP.NET compiles and copies your application to... Often referred to as "Shadow Copies". Your ASP.NET view code typically isn't compiled at compile time and so .NET compiles it to binaries which are placed in this folder at runtime. Other DLLs are also copied to this folder at runtime, which ensures that you can replace the /bin files at any time during execution (via drag and drop for example)... ASP.NET keeps a watch on the bin folder and will refresh the Shadow Copies if a file changes.

Comment: Ok, i understand but why two instance for example of DevExpress.Charts.v12.1.Core.dll are loaded into the ASP.NET web server domain? DevExpress.Charts.v12.1.Core.dll never changed in the bin foler.

Comment: That's a good question. I would guess that that GAC is involved. Can you check the GAC folder and see if there are multiple copies there?

Comment: Yes. There are DevExpress.Data.v11.1 and DevExpress.Utils.v11.1 but no DevExpress.Charts.v12.1.Core.dll ..i din't  remember that i installed devexpres... But even if there were assemblies into GAC they should not be loaded because load context will use first loaded assembly and will not load second assembly with same name